# How assign "Tab" key instead of "Ctrl+Tab" key in ListView?

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a "Listview", such this:

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ...}" >    
     <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
         <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
             <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
             <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="50"/>
             <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="False" />
             <Style.Triggers>
                 <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="true">
                     <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="true" />
                 </Trigger>
             </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
     </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
     <ListView.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemsPanel>
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding ... }" />
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>
```

now the focus navigates the items with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> combination key, but i want handle and replace just <kbd>TAB</kbd> key instead of it.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Student}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Continue" KeyboardNavigation.ControlTabNavigation="None" >
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="50"/>
                <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="False" />

                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="true" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"></StackPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Name }" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Set  KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Continue" KeyboardNavigation.ControlTabNavigation="None"  of ListView . Hope this will help. I have tried it and it worked.